# Finding a great circle vector in between two places on the earths surface.

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

I have derived vectors from the coordinates of New York and Lisbon, but now I need to find the vector of a point between the two locations, which has a great circle distance from New York of 2790.101817km   (Or 2828.356785km from Lisbon).

New York: (1329, -4638, 4159)

Lisbon: (4908, -792, 3983)

*Vectors rounded to avoid decimals

Any help at all on how to go about getting the XYZ vector for this point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf N$ be the vector from the center of the earth to New York.

Let $\mathbf L$ be the vector to Lisbon.

Let $\mathbf X$ be the vector to the unknown point.

Let $\mathbf n$ be the unit vector that is perpendicular to all 3 of them.

Let $d=2790.101817\,\text{km}$ be the distance along the great circle from $\mathbf N$ to $\mathbf X$.

Let $\theta $ be the angle between $\mathbf N$ and $\mathbf X$ in the great circle that connects the 2 of them.

Let $R\approx 6371\,\text{km}$ be the radius of the earth.

Then:
\begin{align}\mathbf n &= \frac{\mathbf N \times \mathbf L}{\|\mathbf N \times \mathbf L\|}\\
\theta &= \frac dR \\
\mathbf X &= \mathbf N\cos\theta + (\mathbf n\times\mathbf N)\sin\theta
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, just a couple of quick questions. The equation you have used for n, is that using the cross product to find the unit vector? and secondly, when you have all of your values to put into the final equation do you do it three times using your different X, Y and Z values each time?

Comment: Yes, it is the cross product. And yes, $\mathbf X$ represents (X,Y,Z). We can calculate them one at a time.